# JS rock, paper, scissors. HTML output

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Javascript code with a rock, paper, scissors game and buttons to make the User choice. The game itself works as right now, it prints out in an HTML element the User choice and the computer choice. I'm at a loss at how to call the compare function and have it display the results that I wrote in there.

HTML:

```
  <button id ="rock"> Rock </button>
  <button id ="paper"> Paper </button>
  <button id ="scissors"> Scissors </button>

 <p id="output" onclick="user()">  </p>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('rock').onclick = user;
document.getElementById('paper').onclick = user;
document.getElementById('scissors').onclick = user;





var computerChoice = Math.random();
     if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
         computerChoice = "rock";
      }else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
         computerChoice = "paper";
      }else{
         computerChoice = "scissors";
      }; 

console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

console.log(compare(userChoice, computerChoice)); 

function compare(choice1, choice2) {

        if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }

    if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins";
        }else{
            return "paper wins";
        }
            }

     if (choice1 === "paper") {
         if (choice2 === "rock") {
             return "paper wins";
          } else {
              return "scissors wins";
          }
         }

         if (choice1 === "scissors") {
         if (choice2 === "rock") {
             return "rock wins";
         } else {
             return "scissors wins";
        }


    }

}

 function user(){
 var userChoice = this.id;
 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = ("User: " + userChoice + ". "         
+ "Computer: "+ computerChoice);
}
```

Comment: `User: " + userChoice + ". "         
+ "Computer: "+ computerChoice + ". " + compare(userChoice, computerChoice)` ?

Comment: It was as simple as that yea, thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the question here? (btw, in the future, try and use markdown to style your questions. And provide as much data as you can. Make the question(s)  cleat. That makes it easier to solve the problem)

Comment: With that said, I see what you're trying to do. And I could easily write some code that would do exactly this for you. However, I assume you're trying to learn something here, and just giving you the code wont teach you anything. Soo my advice would be to take a look at jQuery. (using jquery you should make 3 buttons (just html divs with an unique id)  use those as input, then use the js you have and use jquery to display the result.